# Import another python script, using PythonInterpreter

Tags: jython

I am trying to execute a python method from eclipse using jython. I managed to run it with following code:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(),  
                     System.getProperties(), new String[0]);  

PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("Mypython.py");  
interpreter.eval("MyClassName().MyMethodName()")
```

My problem is when I import another python script, which exists even in the same directory with Mypython.py. For example, when I add:

```
from food import Pizza
```

to Mypython.py, it starts to complain that cannot import. ImportError..

I found some questions about importing python libaries like os, but in my case this is not an issue.

I tried to make the folder as a package, add    **init**.py    etc but it failed.  I saw  some people use PySystemState, but I think it is for jython modules not user python scripts. if this is the solution please give me a simple example.

Could you please help me with that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.path` is your module-import search path.  You can `import sys` and then modify `sys.path` as required.